# H all,, I need to create a formula(text) in Netsuite is anyone is able to give me a hint how to finish it please? UPDATED

Tags: formula, netsuite, case-statement, saved-searches

I need to do this in formula(text) if custitem_prod_grade_field equals A then Pack/Batch Size equals custitem_unitsperpallet ELSE custitem10 * reordermultiple, if any field is null then default to reordermultiple.

This will allow us to order in full layer/pallet quantities and improve receiving efficiencies.

I have created something like this but unsure how to finish it and could not find anything that would help on the internet?

case when {custitem_prod_grade_field} is null or {custitem_unitsperpallet} is null or {custitem10} is null then {reordermultiple} else 0 end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all field ids are real/accurate the following nested case statement should work for you in a netsuite saved search.

```
CASE WHEN {custitem_prod_grade_field} IS NULL THEN {reordermultiple} ELSE 

  (CASE WHEN {custitem_unitsperpallet} IS NULL THEN {reordermultiple} ELSE 

    (CASE WHEN {custitem10} IS NULL THEN {reordermultiple} ELSE 0 END) 

  END)

END
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Martha, yes the ids are accurate, however just wondering about this part  ELSE custitem10 * reordermultiple, with multiply ids and what to do with CASE WHEN {custitem_prod_grade_field} = 'A' , but I got an invalid expression when including that part of the formula? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  If you trying to evaluate the following statement:  If custitem_prod_grade_field is "A" then multiply custitem10 by reordermultiple.  Then the formula would be:  CASE WHEN {custitem_prod_grade_field}= 'A' THEN {custitem10} * {reordermultiple} END

Comment: HI @Martha, yes that's works but I need the whole formula CASE WHEN {custitem_prod_grade_field} = 'A' THEN {custitem10}  = {reordermultiple} ELSE {custitem10} * {reordermultiple} (CASE WHEN {custitem_unitsperpallet} IS NULL THEN {reordermultiple} ELSE (CASE WHEN {custitem10} IS NULL THEN {reordermultiple} ELSE 0 END) END)END something like this one but the syntax is still wrong? :(

Comment: From the formula you provided "THEN {custitem10} = {reordermultiple}" is what's causing an error.  It suggests you intend to set the value of custitem10 to reordermultiple.  I do not know if or how you can set values from a Saved Search.